# Assigning values to array throws an error

Tags: java

Sorry for the bad title; hard for me to explain it. I'm working with a text file in the format of make, model, number. In the text file, there are multiple such lines for this. When my program is started, a constructor is called with the input of my file and it reads the lines of my file, while assigning the values to an object which gets added to my array. The weird thing is, this code only works some of the time. For example, it would work consistently when I had two lines of just make,model,number. However, when I add three lines, it throws an error. Sometimes, I'll rerun the program or add a fourth line and it will work. I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated!:

```
ArrayList<Car> carArray = new ArrayList<Car>();

public CarDealershipSystem(File carFile, File associateFile) {
    //carFile
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(carFile))) {
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
            if (lineArray.length>=3) {
                Car car = new Car();
                car.setMake(lineArray[0]);
                car.setModel(lineArray[1]);
                car.setVin(lineArray[2]);
                carArray.add(car);
            }
            else {
                System.err.printf("%sis not a car.%n", line);
            }
        }   
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `readLine()` it **consumes** a line. You need to store that line or it does not come back. See your annotated code here:

```
while((br.readLine()) != null) { // <-- read a line and compare it to null
    String line = br.readLine(); // <-- read another line
```

It should be something like

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

**or**

```
while (true) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    // ...
```

Make sure there are the correct number of tokens before deciding the line is a `Car`.

```
if (lineArray.length >= 3) {
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setMake(lineArray[0]);
    car.setModel(lineArray[1]);
    car.setVin(lineArray[2]);
    carArray.add(car);
} else {
    System.err.printf("%s is not a car.%n", line);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the feedback. I changed my line to line to that but it still gives me an array out of bounds exception on line 25, which is my car.setModel() method, even though inside my text file there it is model,make,vin. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks again, good suggestion. Unfortunately, my lines return back that they're not a car. Like I said, my lines are model,make,vin and I use the line.split(",") but it doesn't work. Obviously I'm new to coding so I guess I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Look closely at the lines saying they are not cars. You have not shared any of them. But I would believe the message. And now your program does not crash.

Comment: Yep, here are my lines:
make1,model1,1
//I have a few lines like that

Ah I think I figured it out. It was because I'm trying to have something like make,model,vin all on one line and have multiple lines like that. However it doesn't work as I intended it.

Comment: And is the message "make1,model1,1 is not a car." - exactly like that? If so, try copy and paste on the "," (because it must be some other character that looks like a ",").

Comment: So here are both of my lines from my text file(// denotes new line): make1,model1,1//
make2,model2,2

Here is what my console is telling me:
is not a car.//
is not a car.

Comment: Please edit your question into a minimal, reproducible example. Empty lines are not a car. And when the parse fails we print the entire line. Are you certain you're reading the text file you think you are?

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm sure I'm reading from the correct file. I'm not sure how to format new lines in the comments here since I don't use SO very often. But it did indeed tell me that "is not a car." even though I'm reading from the right text file and have text in that text file. I'll try to edit the question to make it easier.

Comment: Don't post images. I see three empty lines after your two lines with cars.

Comment: Right, the text file isn't always going to be completely full. It could be one line or 10 lines. We are constantly adding to this text file. Just realized that lineArray[0] is referencing the whole string and not just one part of the string. I thought that lineArray[0] would return model, not model,make,vin. Sorry.

Comment: `lineArray[0]` is **not** the whole string. `System.err.printf("%s is not a car.%n", line);` - `line` is the whole string.